# equivalent function but different values O.o

Tags: function, haskell, binomial-coefficients

I have 2 function, but for the same input a=5 und b=6 different values -.- why?

f1:

[wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%285^3%2B6^3%29%285^3-6^3%29%29^3%2B3%28%285%286^2%29%2B%285^2%296%29%285%286^2%29-%286^2%296%29%29+%3D](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%285%5E3%2b6%5E3%29%285%5E3-6%5E3%29%29%5E3%2b3%28%285%286%5E2%29%2b%285%5E2%296%29%285%286%5E2%29-%286%5E2%296%29%29%20=)

f2:

[wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285^2-6^2%29^3](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285%5E2-6%5E2%29%5E3)

my haskell code:

```
f :: Double -> Double -> Double
f a b = (((a**3)+(b**3))*((a**3)-(b**3)))+3*((a*(b**2) + (a**2)*a)*(a*(b**2) - (a**2)*a))

h :: Double -> Double -> Double
h a b = ((a+b)*(a-b))**3
```

f-->
[wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28a^3%2Bb^3%29%28a^3-b^3%29%29^3%2B3%28%28a%28b^2%29%2B%28a^2%29b%29%28a%28b^2%29-%28a^2%29b%29%29](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28a%5E3%2bb%5E3%29%28a%5E3-b%5E3%29%29%5E3%2b3%28%28a%28b%5E2%29%2b%28a%5E2%29b%29%28a%28b%5E2%29-%28a%5E2%29b%29%29)

h-->
[wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a^2-b^2%29^3](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%5E2-b%5E2%29%5E3)

Comment: What output were you expecting, and what did you get.  Typically we don't actually run your code, we just look at it and predict what is going on, so it helps if you show us output.

Comment: Main> h 6 5
output => 1331.0
Main> f 6 5
output=> -41436.9999999999

Comment: f :: Double -> Double -> Double
    f a b = ((a**3+b**3)*(a**3-b**3)) + 3*((a*b**2 + a**2*b)*(a*b**2 - a**2*b))

it works =) nice

Comment: Next time be sure to use TEXT for your links and make a proper hyperref.  I have no idea what you're expecting me to get from the links.  Also, the plots show fairly clearly that these functions are not the same - not sure what made you think they are.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions aren't equivalent. Expand each out, and for example the `a**6` terms are different.